# onTapGesture not being called

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have have a View that presents a list that has checkboxes in each row which when tapped they display a checkmark and should add the corresponding the descriptive term to a binding String array. When I tap on the checkbox, the checkmark is displayed but the tap gesture to append the descriptive term is not even reached. If someone could please explain the correct way to call the respective tap gestures.

Here is the code:

**NewWineView**

```
struct NewWineView: View {
    Button(action: {
       descriptorsViewVisible.toggle()
    }, label: {
          HStack{
            Text("Descriptors")
              .font(.custom("Oswald-Bold", size: 20))
              .foregroundStyle(Color.black)
            Spacer()
            Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
              .foregroundStyle(Color.gray)
          }
    })
    .padding([.leading, .trailing],100)
    .padding([.top, .bottom])
}
.sheet(isPresented: $descriptorsViewVisible, onDismiss: {
            print(descriptors)
            descriptorsViewVisible = false
        }, content: {
            WineDescriptorsListView(descriptorArray: $descriptors)
        })
```

**WineDescriptorsListView**

```
struct WineDescriptorsListView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var model: Model
    @Binding var descriptorArray: [String]
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(model.wineDescriptors, id: \.self) { descriptor in
                HStack {
                    Checkbox()
                        .onTapGesture {
                            descriptorArray.append(descriptor)
                        }
                    Text(descriptor)
                        .font(.custom("Oswald-Regular", size: 20))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Checkbox**

```
struct Checkbox: View {
    @State var isChecked: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .aspectRatio(1.0, contentMode: .fit)
                .foregroundStyle(Color.white)
                .border(Color.black) //need to make thicker
                .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                .onTapGesture {
                    isChecked.toggle()
                }
            if isChecked {
                Image(systemName: "checkmark")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Additionally model.wineDescriptors is just an array of descriptive terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two tap gesture recognisers associated with the same element, but only one of these is going to fire.

You need to eliminate one.

I have simplified your code to use a list of possible strings and a `Set` of selected strings but I think it is essentially the same as what you have and you should be able to apply it to your code.

The first strategy you could adopt is to remove the `onTapGesture` from the `Checkbox` and just leave the one in the list row.  This requires that you pass the `isChecked` state in as an argument to `Checkbox`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var selectedItems: Set<String> = []
    let items = ["A","B","C"]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
          List {
            ForEach(items, id:\.self) { item in
                HStack {
                    Text(item)
                    Spacer()
                    Checkbox(isChecked: selectedItems.contains(item))
                        .onTapGesture {
                                if self.selectedItems.contains(item) {
                                self.selectedItems.remove(item)
                            } else {
                                self.selectedItems.insert(item)
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
          }
          Text("Selected:")
          List {
                ForEach(Array(self.selectedItems), id:\.self) { item in
                    Text(item)
                }
           }    
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct Checkbox: View {
   var isChecked: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .aspectRatio(1.0, contentMode: .fit)
                .foregroundStyle(Color.white)
                .border(Color.black) //need to make thicker
                .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                
            if isChecked {
                Image(systemName: "checkmark")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As `selectedItems` is a `Set`, the `contains` check is efficient, although you are probably dealing with a small array so using an array rather than a set probably won't have much impact.

The other strategy is to have the `Checkbox` handle the tap itself, in which case the list needs to pass in some code, via a closure, to be performed in the tap handler:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var selectedItems: Set<String> = []
    let items = ["A","B","C"]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                ForEach(items, id:\.self) { item in
                    HStack {
                        Text(item)
                        Spacer()
                        Checkbox(isChecked: selectedItems.contains(item))
                        { newValue in
                            if newValue {
                                self.selectedItems.insert(item)
                            } else {
                                self.selectedItems.remove(item)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                
            }
            Text("Selected:")
            List {
                ForEach(Array(self.selectedItems), id:\.self) { item in
                    Text(item)
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}


struct Checkbox: View {
    @State var isChecked: Bool
    var action: ((Bool)->Void)?
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .aspectRatio(1.0, contentMode: .fit)
                .foregroundStyle(Color.white)
                .border(Color.black) //need to make thicker
                .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.isChecked.toggle()
                    self.action?(isChecked)
                }
            if isChecked {
                Image(systemName: "checkmark")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I probably prefer this second approach since it separates the functionality; The checkbox handles the tap and updates its checked state.  The list row reacts to that changed state.

Note that even in this second implementation we still need to pass in the `isChecked` value to the `Checkbox` so that it can display correctly based on the current state.